# Azure Data Factory - Check If Any Zip File Exists

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to check if any zip file exists in my SFTP folder. `GetMetadata` activity works fine if I explicitly provide the filename but I can't know the file name here as the file name is embeded with timestamp and sequence number which are dynamic.

I tried specifying `*.zip` but that never works and `GetMetadata` activity always returns `false` even though the zip file actually exists. is there any way to get this worked? Suggestion please.

Sample file name as below, in this the last part `0000000004_20210907080426` is dynamic and will change every time:

```
TEST_TEST_9999_OK_TT_ENTITY_0000000004_20210907080426
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly do a Get Metadata on the folder and include the Child items under the Field List.

You'll have to iterate with a ForEach using the expression

```
@activity('Get Folder Files').output.childItems
```

and then check if `item().name` (within the ForEach) ends with '.zip'.

I know it's a pain when the wildcard stuff doesn't work for a given dataset, but this alternative ought to work for you.

Comment: LOL!! Exactly what I ended up doing to get around this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I used the activity Get Metadata on the folder and include the Child items With the if activity.

Expression of if activity:
the function empty checks if the array  childItem  have data

```
@if( empty( activity('Get Metadata').output.childItems ), false , true )
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This would work but not if you are specifically trying to check a zip file name exists or not. Thanks for answering though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using exists in the `Get Metadata` activity, you need to provide the file name in it.

As a workaround, you can get the child items (with filename *.zip) using the `Get Metadata` activity.

[image]

Output:

[image]

Pass the output to `If Condition` activity, to check if the required **file exists**.

```
@contains(string(json(string(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems))),'.zip')
```

[image]

You can use other activities inside **True** and **False** activities based on If Condition.

[image]

If there is **no file exists** or no child items found in the `Get Metadata` activity.

[image]

If condition output:

[image]

Comment: Great Suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For SFTP dataset, if you want to use a wildcard to filter files under the field specified folderPath, you would have to skip this setting and specify the file name in **activity source settings** (Get Metadata activity).

But Wildcard filter on folders/files is not supported for Get Metadata activity.